# Running Two Threads in Main Method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is it possible to choose which thread to run in the main method? for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        System.out.print("How many entries do you want to make? ");
        entries = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your choice:\n ");
        System.out.print("\n1. Specific file");
        System.out.println("\n2. All files\n");
        userChoice = choiceScanner.nextInt();
        if (userChoice == 1)
           new Thread(new GUIGenerator(entries)).start();
        if (userChoice == 2)
           new Thread(new GUIGenerator2(entries)).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Here, what I want to do is have the program run either the first or second thread depending on what the user enters. Is this possible, or can main only take one thread?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You will have the main thread running concurrently with your new thread (containing either `GUIGenerator` or `GUIGenerator2`).

Comment: Right now, the main method is within GUIGenerator(). I replaced new Thread(new GUIGenerator(entries)).start(); with new GUIGenerator() and it works. Would it still work if I replace new Thread(new GUIGenerator2(entries)).start(); with new GUIGenerator2()? I don't have GUIGenerator2() written yet so I can't test it out like with GUIGenerator().

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind multithreading is that it allows your code to executing instructions in parallel (that is, at the same time.) So if you start a new `Thread` from your main, your new `Thread` will begin its execution, and your `Main` will continue along to the next instruction as if the `Thread` never happened. So yes, it is very possible to execute both a new `Thread` AND the initial program flow at the same time.

Comment: Same remark as for nasukkin. This is a Swing question more than a threading question

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is that you pass a runnable and Swing runs it for you when it can. You're not supposed to run stuff by yourself if it's going to interact with the UI, because there's only one application thread rendering the graphic components. Just by the looks of it, this snippet seems incorrect.

I don't see why you would need to create a new thread at this point, you just need to call whatever code is contained in `GUIGenerator.run` and `GUIGenerator2.run`.

Comment: Right now, the main method is within GUIGenerator(). I replaced new Thread(new GUIGenerator(entries)).start(); with new GUIGenerator() and it works. Would it still work if I replace new Thread(new GUIGenerator2(entries)).start(); with new GUIGenerator2()? I don't have GUIGenerator2() written yet so I can't test it out like with GUIGenerator().

Comment: Would definitely work ! Obviously, neither `GUIGenerator` nor `GUIGenerator` should contain a main method

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to choose which thread to run in the main method?"

**YES**

Rational is that you already did it in your example. There is nothing stopping you from writing logic (such as the if-else conditional you provided) that fires up one implementation of your thread vs another.

Comment: You're missing the Swing particularity of this question, making your answer unrelevant

Comment: Is the Swing portion really that important to the question? What about Swing makes if-else constructs invalid to the original question?

Comment: Swing, like many UI frameworks in Java, has specific rules about multi-threading if you want to avoid freezing your UI. You're not supposed to interact with UI components from any other thread than the application thread. Therefore, the code in the question is incorrect and will most likely lead to rendering glitches